# Error "AdbCommandRejectedException: device not found" in Eclipse using Android emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I've tried to change the build of an application, and now eclipse doesn't work.

There is nothing in the console, and when I launch the debug, there is nothing on the log.

I just got this message :

```
[2011-03-31 11:22:58 - Logcat]device not found
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device not found
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.java:736)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:373)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:284)
    at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogPanel$3.run(LogPanel.java:527)
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server` to restart the adb. It can be found in your android sdk directory, subfolder `plattform-tools`.

Comment: Also you can kill the `adb.exe` process from the Task Manager.

Comment: Which works only on windows :-) (of course you can adapt it to other OSs)

Comment: for the newer api the `adb` moved to the `platform-tools` folder under the `sdk` folder.

Comment: Make sure the adb process is running with sufficient privileges (i.e. super user)

Comment: this process does not work always.Restarting device help me after this process

Comment: I don't know how, but magically, changing usb port worked for me, phew!

Answer (score 3):

**Restart the eclipse once...and try again**

...

Answer (score 3):

on-off your USB debugging on mobile phone or your AVD maybe help you solve this problem. This method is work for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue on Linux. It turned out that my adb server was running under my user account, so running the following fixed the issue:

```
sudo adb kill-server
sudo adb start-server
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same problem.
Go to developers Option and then **Revoke USB debugging authorization**.

Comment: This can be added as comment, once you have enough reputation

Comment: Yes I have started answering on stackoverflow now only.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the eclipse and check if the error continues. 
Also check if you have correct version of AVD manager installed or not.

Comment: How do you check if the version of AVD manager is correct ? Which version should it be ? What are the steps to check that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the **Emulator** and restarting **adb** doesn't solve the problem then close the current running Android virtual device and Launch it again.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason my device had gone offline, reconnecting the device resolved the issue.