# Android DDMS device offline

Tags: android, adb, eclipse-adt

I am using Android platform 4.3 and sdk version 18. When I try to run the helloworld app, the emulator starts, and gets disconnected almost immediately. When I debugged the DDMS view by killing the adb and starting adb again and list the adb, it doesn';t show up any emulator. It throws the following exception:

```
[2014-08-19 16:08:32 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:An existing connection was  forcibly closed by the remote host
[2014-08-19 16:08:33 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
[2014-08-19 16:08:59 - DDMS] device offline
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device offline
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.java:774)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:396)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:347)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:609)
    at com.android.ddmuilib.SysinfoPanel$1.run(SysinfoPanel.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please help finding a solution to this issue on how to associate the emulator with adb.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error "AdbCommandRejectedException: device not found" in Eclipse using Android emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497785/error-adbcommandrejectedexception-device-not-found-in-eclipse-using-android-e)

Comment: I have tried the solution suggested in the possible duplicate link before posting this question here. This is a scenario where the device is offline and is not related to device not found. But none of the solution provided there worked for me.

Comment: Can someone please answer this?