# Cannot run apps error installing APK

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is the error that I got when running my code in Android Studio.

```
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set.
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong. 
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device. 
Error while Installing APK
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error "AdbCommandRejectedException: device not found" in Eclipse using Android emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497785/error-adbcommandrejectedexception-device-not-found-in-eclipse-using-android-e)

Comment: Though you've the answer already in your logcat, your answer is here too -  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5497938/3145960

Comment: Look at the display of your device...